# NSwag Generated C# Client with IFormFile

Tags: c#, nswag, asp.net-core-7.0, iformfile

I am using NSwag to generate a C# client from a dotnet 7 Web API that is consumed by a Blazor WASM application.  I am having trouble getting a Post with an `IFormFile` to upload an attachment with the client.

Here is my API Controller method.  Note that it takes an `IFormFile` parameter.

```
[MapToApiVersion(Constants.ApiVersions.V1)]
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BlobContentInfo), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ValidationError>), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<BlobContentInfo>> Post(
    [FromRoute] int projectId,
    [FromRoute] int equipmentId,
    [FromForm] string? description,
    [FromForm] IFormFile file,
    [FromForm] AttachmentType? attachmentType = null)
{
    return await TryGetAsync<ActionResult<BlobContentInfo>>(async _ =>
    {
        var user = await GetUser();

        var equipment = await Mediator.Send(new GetEquipment { EquipmentId = equipmentId, ProjectId = projectId, User = user });
        if (equipment == null)
            return NotFound();

        var attachment = new AttachmentUpload
        {
            EquipmentId = equipmentId,
            UploadedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            AttachmentType = attachmentType,
            Description = description,
            FormFile = file
        };

        var result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(attachment);

        if (!result.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(result.ToValidationErrors());

        var uploaded = await Mediator.Send(new UploadAttachment
        {
            ProjectId = projectId,
            AttachmentUpload = attachment,
            User = user
        });

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { projectId, equipmentId }, uploaded);
    }, (ex, _) => Error<BlobContentInfo>(ex));
}
```

Here is my Service Method which calls the generated API client method.

1. Note that is splits the `IFormFile` into parameters which make up its constituent parts.  Is there a way to avoid this?
2. Note that the IHeaderDictionary expected by the generated client is of type `Api.Client.IHeaderDictionary` instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary`.  Is there a way to make the generated client use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary` instead?  I've tried an extension method to convert, but this doesn't work as there's no concrete `Api.Client.IHeaderDictionary`.  I've also looked at the `nswag.json`, but I don't see anything in there that could accomplish this.

   ```
   public async Task<ServiceResult<BlobContentInfo>> UploadEquipmentAttachment(
       int projectId,
       int equipmentId,
       AttachmentUpload attachment,
       CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
       return await TryGetAsync(async _ =>
       {
           var response =
               await ApiClient.V1ProjectsEquipmentAttachmentsPostAsync(
                   projectId,
                   equipmentId,
                   attachment.Description,
                   attachment.FormFile.ContentType,
                   attachment.FormFile.ContentDisposition,
                   attachment.FormFile.Headers, // This fails as the NSwag client is expecting Api.Client.IHeaderDictionary instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary
                   attachment.FormFile.Length,
                   attachment.FormFile.Name,
                   attachment.FormFile.FileName,
                   attachment.AttachmentType,
                   cancellationToken);

           return new ServiceResult<BlobContentInfo>
           {
               Status = OperationResult.Success,
               HttpResponseCode = (HttpStatusCode)response.StatusCode,
               Data = response.Result
           };
       }, (ex, _) => Task.FromResult(HandleClientApiException<BlobContentInfo>(ex)));
   }
   ```

Here is my `nswag.json` configuration:

```
{
  "runtime": "Net70",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": "$(Configuration)",
      "runtime": "",
      "targetFramework": "",
      "noBuild": true,
      "msBuildOutputPath": null,
      "verbose": true,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "requireParametersWithoutDefault": false,
      "apiGroupNames": null,
      "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "Default",
      "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
      "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "generateOriginalParameterNames": true,
      "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
      "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
      "generateKnownTypes": true,
      "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
      "generateXmlObjects": false,
      "generateAbstractProperties": false,
      "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
      "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
      "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
      "useXmlDocumentation": true,
      "resolveExternalXmlDocumentation": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceBasePath": null,
      "serviceSchemes": [],
      "infoTitle": "My Title",
      "infoDescription": null,
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
      "documentTemplate": null,
      "documentProcessorTypes": [],
      "operationProcessorTypes": [],
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
      "contractResolverType": null,
      "serializerSettingsType": null,
      "useDocumentProvider": true,
      "documentName": "v1",
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
      "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
      "startupType": null,
      "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
      "useHttpAttributeNameAsOperationId": false,
      "output": null,
      "outputType": "Swagger2",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
      "assemblyPaths": [],
      "assemblyConfig": null,
      "referencePaths": [],
      "useNuGetCache": false
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "configurationClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": true,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": true,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
      "useBaseUrl": true,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": false,
      "generatePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
      "typeAccessModifier": "public",
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "$(ClientClassNamePrefix)Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "SingleClientFromPathSegments",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": true,
      "generateJsonMethods": false,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "wrapResponses": true,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "ApiResponse",
      "namespace": "$(ClientNamespace)",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Poco",
      "jsonLibrary": "NewtonsoftJson",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "generateNullableReferenceTypes": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
      "output": "$(ClientOutDir)"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is where I wire-up the client from `Program.cs`

```
private static void AddTmsCoreApiClient(
        this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddOptions<TmsCoreApiClientSettings>()
            .Bind(configuration.GetSection(TmsCoreApiClientSettings.ConfigSectionName));
        var tmsCoreApiClientSettings = new TmsCoreApiClientSettings();
        configuration.GetSection(TmsCoreApiClientSettings.ConfigSectionName).Bind(tmsCoreApiClientSettings);

        services.AddHttpClient(TmsApiClientName, client =>
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tmsCoreApiClientSettings.BaseUri))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                .ConfigureHandler(
                    authorizedUrls: new[] { tmsCoreApiClientSettings.BaseUri },
                    scopes: tmsCoreApiClientSettings.Scopes
                ));

        services.AddScoped<ICoreApiClient, CoreApiClient>(provider =>
        {
            var httpClient = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient(TmsApiClientName);
            return new CoreApiClient(tmsCoreApiClientSettings.BaseUri, httpClient);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but the only way I could get this to work was by changing the API to accept a byte[] instead of an IFormFile and then converting the byte[] to an IFormFile in the API before sending to Azure Blob storage.